# Issue With HttpClient Bulk Parallel Request in .Net Core C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, parallel-processing, httpclient

So I have been struggling with this issue for like 3 weeks. Here's what I want to do.

So I have like 2000 stock options. I want to fetch 5 of them at a time and process but it all has to be parallel. I'll write them in steps to make it more clear.

1. Get 5 stock symbols from an array
2. Send it to fetch its data and process. Don't wait for a response keep on processing.
3. wait 2.6 seconds (as we are limited to 120 API requests per minute so this delay helps in keeping it throttled to 115 per minute)
4. Goto 1

All the steps above have to be parallel. I have written the code for it and it all seems to be working fine but randomly it crashes saying

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond".

And sometimes it'll never happen and everything works like a charm.

This error is very random. It could show up on maybe 57th stock or maybe at 1829th stock. I have used HttpClient for it. I have tested this same scenario using Angular and creating custom requests and it never crashes there so it's not third-party server's fault.

What I have already done:

1. Changed HttpClient class usage from new instances every time to a single instance for the whole project.
2. Increases Service point manager Connection limit to a different number. (Default for .net core is 2)
3. Instead of HttpClient Queuing I have used SemaphoreSlim for queue and short-circuiting.
4. Forced ConnectionLeaseTimeout to 40 seconds to detect DNS changes if any.
5. Changed Async Tasks to threading.
6. Tried almost everything from the internet.

My doubts:
I doubt that it has something to do with the HttpClient class. I have read a lot of bad things about its misleading documentation etc.

My friend's doubt:
He said it could be because of concurrent tasks and I should change it to threads.

Here's the code:

// Inside Class Constructor

```
private readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
SetMaxConcurrency(ApiBaseUrl, maxConcurrentRequests);
```

// SetMaxConcurrency function

```
private void SetMaxConcurrency(string url, int maxConcurrentRequests)
{
   ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url)).ConnectionLimit = maxConcurrentRequests;
   ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 40*1000;
}
```

// code for looping through chunks of symbol each chunk has 5 symbols/stocks in it

```
foreach(var chunkedSymbol in chunkedSymbols)
{   
    //getting o auth token
    string AuthToken =  await OAuth();
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthToken))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Access Token is null!");
    }
    processingSymbols += chunkSize;
    OptionChainReq.symbol = chunkedSymbol.ToArray();
    async Task func()
    {
        //function that makes request
        var response = await GetOptionChain(AuthToken, ClientId, OptionChainReq);
        // concat the result in main list
        appResponses = appResponses.Concat(response).ToList();
    }

    // if request reaches 115 process the remaning requests first
    if(processingSymbols >= 115)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        processingSymbols = 0;
    }

    tasks.Add(func());

    // 2600 millisecond delay to wait for all the data to process
    await Task.Delay(delay);
}
//once the loop is completed process the remaining requests
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

// This code processes every symbol.  this code is inside GetOptionChain()

```
try{
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string symbol in OptionChainReq.symbol)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Params = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();  
            string requestParams = string.Empty;
            // Converting Request Params to Key Value Pair.  
            Params.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("apikey" , ClientId));
        
            // URL Request Query parameters.  
            requestParams = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Params).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  
        
            string endpoint = ApiBaseUrl + "/marketdata/chains?";
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OAuthToken);
            
            Uri tosUri = new Uri(endpoint + requestParams, UriKind.Absolute);
            async Task func()
            {
                try{
                    string responseString = await GetTosData(tosUri);
                    OptionChainResponse OptionChainRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OptionChainResponse>(responseString);
                    var mappedOptionAppRes =  MapOptionsAppRes( OptionChainRes );
                    if(mappedOptionAppRes != null)
                    {
                        OptionsData.Add( mappedOptionAppRes );
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Crashed");
                }
            }
            // asyncronusly processing each request 
            tasks.Add(func());
        }
        //making sure all 5 requests are processed
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    failedSymbols += " "+ string.Join(",", OptionChainReq.symbol);
}
```

// The code below is for individual request

```
public async Task<string> GetTosData(Uri url)
{
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        if (IsTripped())
        {
            return UNAVAILABLE;
        }

        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
        
        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            string OAuthToken = await OAuth();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OAuthToken);
            return await GetTosData(url);
        }
        else if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            TripCircuit(reason: $"Status not OK. Status={response.StatusCode}");
            return UNAVAILABLE;
        }

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timed out");
        TripCircuit(reason: $"Timed out");
        return UNAVAILABLE;
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of .NET you are using?

Comment: @tia it's 5.0.102

Comment: The web, by its nature, won't work sometimes. Introduce retries.

Comment: @mjwills I tried that. It's a background cron job. Usually, it takes around 18 minutes but with retries, it could take 32 minutes  or so cause once this error starts showing up it keeps showing up.

Comment: I'm following **[This article](https://josef.codes/c-sharp-throttle-http-requests-concurrent/)**  and testing. Seems to be helping till now

Comment: `cause once this error starts showing up it keeps showing up.` You didn't make that clear in your question.

Comment: It keeps showing up for that run only for like 10 20 times and then it'll keep working once again and it might crash again. What I think is that the third-party server is not capable of handling too many parallel requests. Using SemaphorSlim's maxCount param seems to be helping. I'll keep updating the thread.
Thanks